# Play Console Login credentials

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-games, developer-console

My Google play app just got rejected because I didn’t give them any valid login credentials.
My app doesn’t have any login method, it only works that you have to buy a package for real money and then you can play that.
To test buy something shouldn’t be any problem right?
How can I fix this?